# Populate nested array objects using aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Im trying to populate the second nested array after using aggregate $lookup.

This is my original array.

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("607da9c0c7cb26384c7810a6"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2021-04-20T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "clientID" : "601e6dc61766587af8ce76db", 
    "medications" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6065de3aa95e721f587f7528")
        }, 
    ]
}
```

```
{
   from: "medications",
   localField: "medications._id",
   foreignField: "_id",
   as: "medications",
}
```

after using aggregate $lookup I get this result, but I still have nested array "inventory" that I need to populate. I tried adding another $lookup pipeline, but I don't know how the right way to do that.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("607da9c0c7cb26384c7810a6"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2021-04-20T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "clientID" : "601e6dc61766587af8ce76db", 
    "medications" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6065de3aa95e721f587f7528"), 
        "medication": "med 1"
        "schedule": ["9am", "10pm"]
        "inventory":  "ObjectId("6076d55ab6aeb947dca85877")"
    }
}
```

This is the inventory item

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("6076d55ab6aeb947dca85877"), 
   "item": "Inventory item 1",
   "Qty": "10"
}
```

Expected Output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("607da9c0c7cb26384c7810a6"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2021-04-20T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "clientID" : "601e6dc61766587af8ce76db", 
    "medications" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6065de3aa95e721f587f7528"), 
        "medication": "med 1"
        "schedule": ["9am", "10pm"]
        "inventory":  {
              "_id" : ObjectId("6076d55ab6aeb947dca85877"), 
              "item": "Inventory item 1",
              "Qty": "10"
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one or alternatively use population.

```
{
   from: "medications",
   localField: "medications._id",
   foreignField: "_id",
   as: "medications",
}
, {
  $unwind: {
    path: "$medications",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
  }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: "inventory",
    localField: "inventory._id",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "medications.inventory",
  }
}
```

You may check the $unwind in the official documentation. Just pay attention to the appropriate `localField` and `foreignField`.

Comment: Is there any other way to expand multiple nested references. Cz its weird to code 4 or 5 lookups just to expand nested references.

Answer (score 0):

use `populate()` to expand nested references.

```
schemaModel.populate(result, {path: 'result'});
```

See more at [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents)